# Build Custom View with allways same Layout

Tags: android, layout, custom-controls, android-custom-view

I have made my own layout for a Button. Normaly I create a View by this:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity());
myButton = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybutton, null, false);
```

Now my idea is that the Class myButton extends View and I do not have to write these lines for each Button. But how can I bring these two lines in myButton Constructor? I can't write:

```
public MyButton(Context c)
{
    this = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mybutton, null, false);
}
```

How can I build a custom View which has allways the same layout so I can build a new myButton with a preloaded layout like this:

```
MyButton myButton = new MyButton();
```

This is the layout I want to use for myButton:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/cell_shape"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/PaddingBottom"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/PaddingHorizontal"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/PaddingHorizontal"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/PaddingTop" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Fach"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/MarginTop"
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Klasse"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/MarginTop"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Raum"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

```
public MyButton extends LinearLayout 
{
    public MyButton(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);
        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.myButton, this, true);
        //other initialization...
    }
}
```

With this XML-Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Own Layout -->
</merge>
```

Comment: Solution looks quite wierd to me. You are extending a viewgroup to create a view. Later with merge, you are asking android to remove this rendant view group. Not a good design

Answer (score 1):

You can still reuse a button with xml which is practically independent of any layout. Just create a `button.xml` in drawable folder that will define all your button properties. This is an example of button layout that has a custom custom corner radius and color gradient (you need to define these colors in `res/values/colors.xml`,of course):

```
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/pressed1"
            android:endColor="@color/pressed2"
            android:angle="90" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:state_focused="true">
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:endColor="@color/focused1"
            android:startColor="@color/focused2"
            android:angle="270" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/default1"
            android:endColor="@color/default2"
            android:angle="90" />
        <corners android:radius="4dp" />
        <padding
            android:left="20dp"
            android:top="10dp"
            android:right="20dp"
            android:bottom="10dp" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Whenever you need to reuse it, you can just create a button view as usual:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:text="@string/button_text">
        </Button>
```

Comment: okay thanks for that but is it impossible the way I thought? In my eyes the way I thought it is mouch easier and comfortabler. I can have my own public and private methods with it so I think it is a better way to build it. Maybe a bit like MVVM.

Comment: Of course you can. You just need to extend the `Button` or CompoundButton` class and set the same drawable.

Comment: I don't understand how a drawable can help me in this case. I updated my first post with the layout I want to use for myButton. Maybe you can have a look on that.